# Why is interface covariance required in this case?

Tags: c#, generics, covariance, contravariance

I am making a common action filter, depending on common, generic services to perform a certain task across multiple similar projects.

#### Structure

1. **Base filter** - contains the logic and accepts a service parameter in the constructor:

   ```
   public abstract class BaseFilter
   {
       ...
       public BaseFilter(IService<IEntity> service)
       ...
   }
   ```
2. **Generic service interface**: `public interface IService<TEntity>`
3. **Base entity**: `public class BaseEntity : IEntity`
4. **Concrete entity**: `public class ConcreteEntity : BaseEntity`
5. **Concrete filter**:

   ```
   public class ConcreteFilter : BaseFilter
   {
       public ConcreteFilter(IService<ConcreteEntity> service) : base(service)
       {
       }
   }
   ```

This is the basic solution structure - a common layer of services and infrastructure, which is then often derived with platform-specific (`ConcreteFilter` in the example) classes to pass in the platform-specific entities as generic parameters.

#### The problem

The above does not compile:

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Service<ConcreteEntity>' to 'Service<IEntity>'
```

I know I can fix it with **covariant** service interface:

```
public class IService<out TEntity>
```

However I would like to avoid that. In this platform (Let's call it **ConcretePlatform**) the generic parameter will always be `ConcreteEntity`, since it's wired like that in the container. I don't want to restrict the generic parameter in **outer-position**, because I have overloads that accept `TEntity`. C# already checks during compile-time, if the given type implements `IEntity`, which means that it is type-safe, as far as I can tell. I can't really foresee a problem, but even it could happen - I am completely fine with **run-time exception**, since this is dependency wiring and it cannot slip in production, unless in case of a major-major developer oversight.

A possible fix would be to use `IEntity` as parameter type instead and then cast to `TEntity` inside each method, however this cast is completely redundant.

#### Thoughts

1. Are any of my claims/understandings wrong? If so please explain how and why.
2. I would like to avoid co/contra variance, because it should be relevant if I try to mix base and derived types somehow, which is NOT at all what I am doing. Furthermore it would inevitably lead to boilerplate casting.

Comment: "I have overloads that accept `TEntity`" - Your `Service<ConcreteEntity>` won't cope with a different type implementing `IEntity`, which a `Service<IEntity>` has to be able to deal with. The compiler is right to stop this compiling.

Comment: It is an error to believe that the inheritance relationship `B : A` propagates to `T<B> : T<A>`. `T<B>` and `T<A>` are two completely unrelated types unless they are explicitly made co- or contra-variant, which is only possible if the generic type appears exclusively in outputs OR inputs. Which limits the use of variance very much.

Comment: Thanks  @Damien_The_Unbeliever, Oliver.  In other words, I have to make the generic parameter **outer** in order for it to be covariant. No way around it. What do you think of my potential solution - using `IEntity` instead of `TEntity` as argument type and then casting to `TEntity`?

Comment: Maybe you could solve it by making `BaseFilter` generic: `public abstract class BaseFilter<TEntity> where TEntity : IEntity {  public BaseFilter(IService<TEntity> service){} }`.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Sadly, I cannot, because I need to derive from `ActionFilterAttribute`. The casting solution seems to work in my own testing. Do you foresee any problems there?

Comment: You can derive from a non-generic class and make the new class generic. Sometimes casting is just required. But in this case make `IService` non generic and make `IEntity` hardwired.